# How would one go about creating a trigger to delete corresponding tuples from a separate table?

Tags: oracle, triggers, sqlplus

For example, you delete a row in one table, and it links to entries in a corresponding table.  This trigger should delete the tuples from this second table (assumingly where their foreign keys match) upon deleting from the first table.  In other words, a cascade delete.  Pretend that the cascade delete option cannot be added to the table.

I'm using Oracle/SQL Plus and here's my attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER delCascade
    BEFORE DELETE ON student
    REFERENCING OLD AS oldRow
    FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM taking
    WHERE taking.studentnum = oldRow.studentnum;
END;
/
```

I keep getting a warning:

```
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

Comment: Cannot get more info about those compilation errors?

Comment: If there is a way to get more info, I do not know about it.  But considering that it's Oracle, I can assume it's not going to get more specific.

Comment: It will get much more specific. Do 'show errors' after you get the warning and will tell you the actual error and the line number it's on. You're missing a `:` before `oldRow` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER delCascade
    BEFORE DELETE ON student
    REFERENCING OLD AS oldRow
    FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM taking
    WHERE taking.studentnum = :oldRow.studentnum;
END;
```

Comment: Well, that definitely got rid of the warning!  Now I can finally test to see if it even works as intended.  Would you mind elaborating on what in the world that single colon does and why it's required?

Comment: @TheRationalist, here your are accessing old variable values and in oracle all bind variables, old and new qualifiers must precede with `:`

Comment: Anyone knows if it makes a difference if I use `BEFORE DELETE` or `AFTER DELETE` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Given a

```
STUD(rollno, name, birthdate)
RESULT(rollno, marks)
```

1)Write a trigger which deletes every related record from `RESULT` table if student record is deleted.

```
create or replace trigger del_trg
after delete on stud_trg
for each row
begin
    if deleting then
        delete from result where stud_trg.rollno=result.rollno;
    end if;
end;
```